# Background Image not 'Blurring-up' when is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a web site in which a smaller version of the backgroud image is put in place until the image is fully loaded.
After the intended image is loaded, a function is fired to apply a CSS class that makes the original smaller and pixelated background an effect of sharp-up the image.

My problem is that in the first time that the pages loads this effect it's not visible, if the page is refreshed the effect is visible and looks as intended.

I'm trying to make [something similar as this site](https://css-tricks.com/the-blur-up-technique-for-loading-background-images/).

this is my page http://vetta.io/

my JS script:

```
//desktop version
 $('<img/>').attr('src', './img/backgroundBig.jpg').on('load', function() {
                $(this).remove();  
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bg-wide', "url('../img/backgroundBig.jpg')");
                $('.overlay-img').addClass('sharp-in');
            });

//tablet
           $('<img/>').attr('src', './img/backgroundMobile.jpg').on('load', function() {
                $(this).remove();  
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bg-narrow', "url('../img/backgroundMobile.jpg')");
                 $('.overlay-img').addClass('sharp-in');
           });
```

In the script i try to load the image and when is loaded i change the CSS variable to the actual image, and add a class that has the 'sharp-up' animation of the image.

The CSS variables initially they have the smaller and pixelated version in base 64.

What i can do to apply this effect always?

Comment: Questions seeking help with ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @LGSon I said the code works but _after the page is refreshed or already in cache_, also i put the page (which is quite simple)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your low definition image as a sibbling of your hd image, make it fit the content of it's parent so we will not see the loading high definition image, and then, when your hd image is fully loaded, simply remove the blurred overlay.

Here is an example to illustrate :

html

```
<div>
    <img id="hd-image" src="path">
    <div id="blurred-image"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#hd-image {
    position: relative;
}
#blurred-image {
    background-image: url('path/to/blurred/image');
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

jquery

```
$('#hd-image').on('load', function() {
    $('#blurred-image').fadeOut();
});
```